# How to convert each array Element as individual array in javascript or loadash

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

Hi i am having an array like this,
I want to make each Element as  an array, i used chunk in lodash but no use. The

```
[ 'Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 4', 'Product 5', 'Product 6' ]
```

Result i am expecting is like this

```
[[ 'Product 1'],['Product 2'], ['Product 3'], ['Product 4'], ['Product 5'],['Product 6' ]]
```

can anybody Help Me on this

Answer (score 3):

if it is a onedimensional array, you can use the `map` function:

```js
var arr = ['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 4', 'Product 5', 'Product 6'];


var result = arr.map(function(el) {
  return [el];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good use of a native function over a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this also -

```
var arr1 = ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4'];

var arr2 = [];

for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
   var temparr = [];
   temparr.push(arr1[i]);
   arr2.push(temparr);
}
console.log(arr2);
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sajalsuraj/89vLty7k/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out..

```js
 var x = [ 'Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 4', 'Product 5', 'Product 6' ]
      var y = [];
      for(var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
        var temp = [x[i]];
        y.push(temp);
      }
      console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in Node.js or is ES6 environment you could do:

```
let arr = products.map(p => [p]);
```

**Example: http://www.es6fiddle.net/ips7zgh0/**